# Super sensitive file system!

Tags: boot, grub2, filesystem, fsck

I have my current laptop for almost 4 years, but it's about 7 months that I have been using Linux (Ubuntu 18.04) as my only OS. There have been challenges for me (you know normally as a new user) to get familiar with Linux, but things are fine except one big issue which doesn't seem to be normal.
My **file system is very sensitive and gets corrupted very easily** just for no reason, and these corruptions are in different levels:

- Sometimes it just simple and while booting needs `fsck /dev/sda1` (Still wired! Why a normal computer needs that time to time?)
- Sometimes when I'm using my computer suddenly the **whole file system becomes read-only**. This happened maybe 3-4 for times in past month. I just should reboot and it again requires `fsck /dev/sda1`
- Sometimes while booting I get the error **Try to read/write out side of the (hd0)** which the solution is doing the `set root=(hd0,msdos1) ...` and you know the rest. Although the last time  that happened (after an unexpected shutdown) it just didn't get fixed by setting root and prefix and I had to do the next case.
- The most hard case is when absolutely nothing works is to boot Linux with live USB and run this command: `sudo e2fsck -f -b 32768 -y /dev/sda1` !! Which has been my life saver all the time. Actually a period of time I had to do it always but after updating GRUB it usually gets fixed by first case.

However all these cases happen to me time to time with different frequency. Pretty annoying haw? I don't know if all of them are caused by same problem or not but this is the whole story of me and my machine's file system. Is it about an physical issue of my Hard Disk? Or my PC (Lenovo Z5070) not being compatible with the Ubuntu. Or maybe just some solvable issue?

And the last thing to mention is that I really didn't have these issues at all when I was using Win 10, and I kinda believe that if I switch to Windows things would be normal again.

So any ideas or clue for my situation? That would really help.

Thanks

==============================

**UPDATE:** I used some disk health check tools and surprisingly the result seems to be fine! Although I couldn't do the self-test in `Disks` but the showing result seems fine. About the **SELF-TEST FAILED** I read that it can be about because some sectors are used and it can't test, so I boot up using live USB but same thing happened. However before test it says: `Disk is OK` and all assessments as you can see is OK too. I also used `SmartMonTool` which is another tool for disk health check, and the result was *PASSED* too.

[Result of Disks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkXRZ.png)

[Result of smartcrl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INYfP.png)

Comment: Step 1: Look up how to run a SMART test on your hard drive. Chronically corrupted filesystems are a classic symptom of a dying hard drive.

Comment: It's ok. You can just restore from backups. No problems, right?

Comment: Are you dual-booting with Windows?

Comment: @user535733 I'll do a SAMRT test and will tell you the result. Thanks

Comment: @jdv I actually didn't get exactly what you meant. Restore backups of my data? Or just file system? File system just gets corrupt and I repair each time but data is still there and no problem with that.

Comment: @heynnema No I don't I erased everything and Installed Ubuntu. I actually kinda couldn't do the dual-boot. I shrank part of my disk to and tried to install Ubuntu alongside windows but the option was disabled, I did everything but still couldn't do that, so I forgot Windows.

Comment: Use the `Disks` app to check your disk's SMART data & tests. Look for values regarding "sectors". Check your BIOS version. See https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-z-series-laptops/lenovo-z50-70/downloads/ds100528 and https://workaround.org/article/updating-the-bios-on-lenovo-laptops-from-linux-using-a-usb-flash-stick/. When you installed Ubuntu, did you lay down a fresh MBR/GPT partition table?

Comment: @ErfanSamieyan I'm suggesting you think about disaster recovery. If your disk is not failing now, it will eventually fail anyway. Are you ready for that?

Comment: @heynnema I used `Disks` and `SmartMonTools` and both seems be showing fine result of my disk (see post update). About the BIOS I don't know what should I do. You really think updating BIOS may solve this problem?

Comment: @jdv Actually I am prepared for any disk problem, but actually I'm not sire if the hard is really damaged or not. I still think are some other issues (which is not physical). Please check the updated.

Comment: @ErfanSamieyan It's always important to keep up with BIOS updates. The last one for your machine was in 2015! Really though, your HDD may be failing.

Comment: @heynnema As you said the last update is for 2015 so I don't think there is anything new which I miss.

Comment: Smart status negatives don't mean a thing. Only smart positives (i.e. smart says there is a problem). Your drive is failing. Different file systems will behave differently but almost certainly windows would eventually start behaving poorly. Unless you have some very specific drivers or a custom kernel or some special process causing what are serious filesystem problems what you describe is a hardware problem.

Comment: @jdv you certainty made me kinda sure that there is something wrong with my HDD :D So I think there is nothing I can do for now. I can wait till it dies itself or replace it before that. Thanks for you help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay guys, it's been a tough few months for me dealing with the described issue. I erased the whole disk several times tried different partitioning and even tried a different distro in order to test everything. But none of them solved the problem and finally crisis happened and my BIOS couldn't recognize my HDD so that was the end and now I'm with a new SSD which has been working without those problems for some weeks. If you are dealing with same issues you should consider replacing the drive. Also take a look at the comments, there is a good conversation there I think. However these are my experiences from what I've done. Some of them are maybe for new users or young learners:

- In my opinion any of mentioned issues can be a sign of damaged hard drive. So if you have to do any manual `fsck` start to think about data backup.
- Hard drives are one of the most sensitive parts of our computers so it is not unlikely at all to have disk issues after sometime (usually within 3-5 years based on your works)
- I have been on very tough moments when I had projects to be done while those hard issues kept happening, but I found out that there would be no learning when there is no problem to deal with. So don't be afraid of issues, don't get settled with an OKAY situation. Try to make things in your most desired form. Specially with computers, they are YOUR machine and should be in the exact way that YOU want. So you even can enhance the best situation.

Have fun in your explores :)

Comment: And remember to do backups !! And do backups ...